# ASP.NET MVC 2: Why does my app reference both versions (1 and 2)?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, assemblybinding

I opened up the DLL for an ASP.NET MVC 2 project of mine in Reflector, and noticed that there are two references to System.Web.Mvc - one for version 1.0.0.0, and one for 2.0.0.0. I don't seem any references to v1 anywhere in the csproj file, nor in my web.config file, but when I try to run the app I get the error `Could not load file or assembly 'System.Web.Mvc, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies.`

Where would the dependency on v1 be coming from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably have an indirect reference to v1 through a different assembly.

Comment: UGH. Embarrassing. *my* assemblies were fine, but I'm using xVal to help with validation, which references v1. I'm not even sure if I need xVal anymore with v2.